# Appending item to a list within dictionary without checking if the key exists

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Currently, in order to do what I'm describing, I have a code like this:

```
if key in dict:
    dict[key].append(item)
else:
    dict[key] = [item]
```

Is there any way I can append to list within dictionary without doing the explicit check?

Can this be done using another data structure?

What I need to do is to track all the items that have some parameter equal.

Comment: Are you sure `dict[key] = item` is correct? Shouldn't that be `dict[key] = [item]`?

Comment: I think it works either way. I'll change it to make it less confusing.

Comment: You probably want a `defaultdict`.  It was made for exactly this situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
d = {}    
d.setdefault(1, []).append('item')
```

in python `.get` used to retrieve key and optional argument to get if value not exist, however it will give you only initial value.
whereas in `.setdefault` you will get a value for corresponding key or else it will initialise key with default value passed as another argument